# Teradata row not delivered (trget): The format or data contains a bad character

Tags: sas, string-formatting, teradata

I am using SAS 9.4 to pull the data from Teradata tables and I have the following error

```
  Teradata row not delivered (trget): The format or 
data    contains a bad character 

  Proc sql;
  Connect to Teradata(user=......)
   Create table table1 as
   Select * from connection to Teradata
  (Select 
     Text1,
      Text2
      From TeraTable
      Where timeperiod between ‘2017-07-01’ and ‘2017-07-15’
   Quit;
```

The text1 and text2 may contain some special characters.

Does anyone have solution?

Comment: What data type(s) are your target fields?

Comment: Character variables

Comment: Note that SAS does not support the `PERIOD` data type.  Or `BIGINT`.  Also some formats for `DECIMAL` data type are going to be incompatible with SAS as they will have more significant digits than SAS's floating point numbers can store.  Also if Teradata has CLOB or BLOB data types those would not be supported by SAS.

Answer (score 0):

try few things.

1. cast(timeperiod as date) between '2017-07-01' and '2017-07-15'
2. check the values in timeperiod, there might be some values which cannot be converted to date. I have seen this many times where values in character is not in form to get converted  into date and query fails.
3. run below query with only text1 and text2 and without where clause.

   Select  top 10
     Text1,
     Text2
     From TeraTabl

third point will make clear that there is no problem with text1 and text2 columns. Top 10 is like outobs=10 in SAS

4. one way to find bad characters in timeperiod columns at high level(non tested code) for character( if it in form of yyyy-mm-dd)

   select  case when substr(timeperiod,1,2) in ('20','19') then 'y' else 'n' 
     end as firstyearpartok,
     case when cast(substr(timeperiod,1,2) as integer) between 1 and 99 then 'y' 
     else 'n' end as lastyearpart,
     case when cast(substr(timeperiod,6,2) as integer) between 1 and 12 then 'y' 
     else 'n' end as monthpart,
     case when cast(substr(timeperiod,6,2) as integer) between 1 and 31 then 'y' 
     else 'n' end as daypart/* this again does not address febrauary 30 or 31*/
    from teratbl

   see whether you have 'n' in above 4 columns

Comment: while querying,  bad data or format issues mostly pop up when there are some data type conversions or character set conversions  either implicitly or explicitly